# Cannot Read Property 'Subscribe' of Undefined Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

I'm having an issue passing in the values for my actionmenuline. The actionmenuline value is passing in undefined and i'm unsure of what's going on.

The service is passing in the correct code for the first value but not the second value. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in the getAction call that's not getting the correct object.

This is the error i'm getting: -->

Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at new ActionViewComponent (actionview.component.ts:68) which line 68 is pointing to this.actionMenuSubscription

**Action View Component**

```
export class ActionViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    // User Fields
    currentUser: User;
    users: User[] = [];
    currentUserSubscription: Subscription;


    // Menu Lines
    currentActionMenuLine: ActionMenuLine;
    actionMenuLines: ActionMenuLine[] = [];
    actionMenuSubscription: Subscription;

    dataSource: any = new MatTableDataSource(ACTION_DATA);

    constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private actionService: ActionService,
        private menuService: MenuService,
    ) {
        this.currentUserSubscription = this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
          this.currentUser = user;
        });

        this.actionMenuSubscription = this.menuService.currentActionMenuLine.subscribe(actionmenuline => {
          this.currentActionMenuLine = actionmenuline;
        });
    }

   public getActions() {
      this.actionService.getAction(this.currentUser, this.currentActionMenuLine).
      subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.dataSource = data;
        });
    }

}
```

**Action Service**

```
export class ActionService {

  public apiURL = 'http://localhost:15217/api/actions/launchaction';
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;
  public currentAction: Observable<Action>;
  private currentActionSubject: BehaviorSubject<Action>;
  public ActionMenuLine: Observable<ActionMenuLine>;


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.currentActionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Action>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentAction')));
      this.currentAction = this.currentActionSubject.asObservable();
    }
      // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  getAction( user: User, actionmenuline: ActionMenuLine) {
      return this.http.post<User[]>(this.apiURL,
        {
            SessionID:  user.userEnv.sessionId,
            ActionTag: actionmenuline.targetActionTag
       })
        .pipe(
          retry(1),
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
  }
```

**Menu Service**

```
export class MenuService {

public currentUser: Observable<User>;
private currentActionMenuLineSubject: BehaviorSubject<ActionMenuLine>;
public currentActionMenuLine: Observable<ActionMenuLine>;
ActionMenuSubscription: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

loadActionMenu(user: User): Observable<ActionMenuLine[]> {
    return this.http.get<ActionMenuLine[]>(`/menu/getlines/`, {
        params : {
            userId: user.id,
            sessionId: user.userEnv.sessionId
        }
    }).pipe(map( MenuLines => {
        return this.debugLines(MenuLines) as ActionMenuLine[];
    }));
}

debugLines(lines: ActionMenuLine[]){

    let i:number = 0;
    let kids:ActionMenuLine[];

    for( let i:number = 0; i< lines.length; i++ ){
        let j:ActionMenuLine = lines[i];
        kids = j.children;
    }

    return lines;
}

loadAboutSyntelic():Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>('usersettings/aboutsyntelic/').pipe(map( AboutSyntelic => {
        return AboutSyntelic as string[];
    }));
}

loadMimic(sessionId: string):Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>("usersettings/mimicdata/",{
        params: {
            sessionId: sessionId
        }
    }).pipe(map(ids => ids as string[]));
}

mimic(userId: string, sessionId: string){
    return this.http.get<any>("usersettings/mimic/",{
        params : {
            userId: userId,
            sessionId: sessionId
        }
    }).pipe(map( res => {
        return res as User
    }));
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that is the problem, but did you tried without your pipe in your getAction method?

Comment: eh tried that, but i'm sure thats not it. this is the error it gives back. Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at new ActionViewComponent (actionview.component.ts:68), which line 68 is the this.actionMenuSubscription

Comment: Could you provide the code of your MenuService? Looks like there is the problem.

Comment: just added the menu service in the code

Comment: Do you use tslint?

Comment: yes I do but i'm not getting any errors from the linter, the code still compiles

Answer (score 2):

`currentActionMenuLine` is defined in **`MenuService`** but with *no value assigned in entire class*.

**MenuService.ts**

```
public currentActionMenuLine$: Observable<ActionMenuLine>;
```

> The service is passing in the correct code for the first value but not the second value.

That's because maybe you are assigning a value to it in **`AuthenticationService`**, which not presented in your question.

check your **AuthenticationService** class and do the same here for `currentActionMenuLine`(add the initial value).

**P.S:**

> Generaly we use  **`$`** symbol  at the end of variable name for Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your service to

```
getAction( user: User, actionmenuline: ActionMenuLine): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post<User[]>(this.apiURL,
        {
            SessionID:  user.userEnv.sessionId,
            ActionTag: actionmenuline.targetActionTag
       })
  }
```

instead of adding pipe to service use it in your component, and in your component

```
public getActions() {
  this.actionService.getAction(this.currentUser, this.currentActionMenuLine)
    .pipe(retry(1))
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
         this.dataSource = data;
   });
}
```

Comment: tried that, but I think the issue happens in the component. this code is returning as undefined.   this.actionMenuSubscription = this.menuService.currentActionMenuLine.subscribe(actionmenuline => {
          this.currentActionMenuLine = actionmenuline;
        });

Answer (score 0):

There's no code to initialize the `currentActionMenuLine` in the `menuService`. You have typed it as an `Observable` but it won't have any effect at runtime as the value is still `undefined`.